# Angular custom validator for reactive form md-error not showing

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I can't get my `*ngIf` to show up if passwords don't match.

```
<md-form-field>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Repeat password" type="password" formControlName="repeat">
    <md-error *ngIf="form.controls['repeat'].errors?.required">Field required</md-error>
    <md-error *ngIf="form.errors?.matchingPasswords">passwords don't match</md-error>
</md-form-field>
```

Here's my constructor

```
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      username:
      ['',
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3),
          Validators.maxLength(30),
          this.validateUsername,
          this.validateUsernameAvailability
        ])
      ],
      email:
      ['',
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.maxLength(30),
          this.validateEmail
        ])
      ],
      password:
      ['',
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(8),
          Validators.maxLength(30),
          this.validatePassword
        ])
      ],
      repeat: ['',
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required
        ])
      ]
    }, {validator: this.matchingPasswords('password', 'repeat')});
  }

  matchingPasswords(password, repeat) {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      // Check if both fields are the same
      if (group.controls[password].value === group.controls[repeat].value) {
        return null; // Return as a match
      } else {
        return { 'matchingPasswords': true }; // Return as error: do not match
      }
    };
  }
```

[image: Here's a screenshot]

@EDIT
Using a simple `<span>` instead of `<md-error>` seems to fix it.

`<span *ngIf="form.errors?.matchingPasswords">passwords don't match</span>`

But why doesn't the `<md-error>` show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a '**[bug'](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4027#issuecomment-305519804)** that needs a workaround.

`md-error` inside `md-form-field` just validates that specific input, taking no regard to any other inputs. So if you move that *outside* the `md-form-field` it will validate, but of course the css will be messed up in that case. The a fix is to use `md-hint` instead and just modify that with css to emulate the `md-error`:

```html
<md-hint *ngIf="form.errors?.matchingPasswords">passwords don't match</md-hint>
```

Just to throw it out there you could skip the custom validator and use **[Custom Error Matcher](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#custom-error-matcher)** like so:

```ts
myErrorStateMatcher(control: FormControl): boolean {
  if(control.parent.controls.password.value === control.value) {
    control.setErrors(null)
    return false;
  }
  else {
    control.setErrors({notSame:true})
    return true;
  }
}
```

in template:

```html
<input mdInput formControlName="repeat" [errorStateMatcher]="myErrorStateMatcher">
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hidz0qsDGiUe7bRg2CkA?p=preview)**

But with this you really have no control of when this is fired. Though with the code you have currently your custom validator is also fired whenever **any** change is happening to form. With that, check the *sidenotes* below.

---

**Sidenotes**:

If going with `md-hint` I'd wrap the `password` and `repeat` inside a nested form group and apply the custom validator to that nested form group, so that it's only fired when changes happen to either of those two form controls.

As for the `repeat` form control, I see no need to use any other validation, than to check if it matches the `password` field.